# URL requested does not match the just-created upon image upload to Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

An image is uploaded to the FirebaseStorage and it gets an URL. Then, a reference is created in FirebaseDatabase where some text is stored along with the image URL of the uploaded image.

Below is whole code which is basically responsible for both uploading the image to FirebaseStorage and creating the database reference for it with a String value of the URL of that image along with a couple of other strings under a uid in database:

```
private void startPosting(){
    final String title_val = et_title.getText().toString().trim();
    final String desc_val = et_description.getText().toString().trim();
    StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("Post_images").child(resultUri.getLastPathSegment());
    filepath.putFile(resultUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();
                newPost.child("title").setValue(title_val);
                newPost.child("description").setValue(desc_val);
                newPost.child("image").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());
                finish();
            }
        });        
}
```

When I upload an image from my phone (camera shot or gallery) it successfully stores it in the FirebaseStorage and simultaneously creates a database reference in FirebaseDatabase. And *about half of the time* it works, the URL in the database "image" and the URL in the storage under "Post_images" MATCH, and the app works just as intended.

**BUT**, also *about half of the time* they DO NOT MATCH, in fact their (?alt=media&token...) latter parts, while the filepaths prior to that are the same.

Here is an example of the non-matching URLs error:

This is the URL of the image in the FirebaseStorage:

[image]

And this is the URL in the FirebaseDatabase which is supposed to be the same:

[image]

But it's NOT, their latter parts (?alt=media&token...) are different...

I've checked onto the Android Monitor and it obviosly tries to get the URL listed in the database, but such does not exist anymore:

[image]

I've checked, copied and pasted the URL, it's not working (error 403, image not found). So I'm really confused, seems to me that this method doesn't give me the correct URL obviously:

```
Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
```

Any ideas and help will be appreciated!

Comment: I'm pretty sure I saw the exact same problem earlier. Was that yours too? If so: why did you delete that question?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, it was me. I've decided to rewrite and make it more clear, and yes I've deleted the previous question.

Comment: That's not how Stack Overflow works. If it's the same problem: edit your question to provide the clearer description. Now I had to redo the edits (the question is not about Android Studio, but about an Android app so should not be tagged with [android-studio]).

Comment: Ah okay, I thought that since I'm using android studio it is relevant, and that [android] is too general. Anyways, thanks for the guide, I'll keep that in mind for the future posts.